# ubuntu 16.04 simple scan on brother j480 has no color

Tags: scanner, colors, simplescan

I have a Brother J480 printer/scanner. The scanner is working with simple scan (and the printer is obviously also working). The problem is the scan produces a grey scale image, not a color image.

To check if the problem is in the printer itself, I did a copy from the glass to the printer. This uses only the printer. The image was printed in color which means the scanner can scan color.

I was unsuccessful in getting simple scan to get a color image, only grey scale is received. Is there something inside simple scan, or somewhere else which will allow me to get a color image?

I have an HP printer where simple scan has no problems with color. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Brother provides Linux drivers for its printer/scanner models. Have you installed a driver for your model? Maybe http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcj480dw_us_eu_as helps further.

Comment: I've installed everything which meets the eye (from the Brother site). In fact simple scan does work, just not in color. Very strange...

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/921210/236230). It worked for me. Basically I installed and used `xsane` which scanned in color.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed. Apparently, the driver was not installed completely correctly. I first removed the existing printer definition (because the installation makes its own icon in the list of available printers).

The link is [brother driver](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcj480dw_us_eu_as&os=127). Click on the Driver Install Tool. You will need to extract the tool, open a terminal and use "sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1 MFC-J480DW". You will need to know the IP of the printer, e.g. 192.168.0.105.

In my case, when it finished, the color scan worked.

Answer (score 0):

The color scanning also confused me. 
If you scan  as "text"  it will be black  & white, 
while if you scan as  "photo" it will be color.
(The choice  is in the drop-down "Scan" menu.)