# SimpleScan detects scanner but scanner does not phisically Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: drivers, gnome, canon, scanner

SimpleScan detects my Canon Lide20 scanner.
[image]

When I start scaning, it seems working but makes a "fake" scanning, black rectangle grows simulating a scanner process, but scanner does not start phisically, no lights, scanner head not moving, etc.
[image]
and then[image]

this is the output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b56b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04a9:220d Canon, Inc. CanoScan N670U/N676U/LiDE 20
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any ideas? Thx!

Answer (score 2):

`Simple scan` is a very basic app for scanning.  You can install `xsane` and do a scan either from `xsane` or using `gimp` since those two are fully compatible (`xsane` installs the appropriate `gimp` extension automatically) and `xsane` delivers extremely better results and has many more options.

`apt-get install xsane`

Comment: Given that Simple Scan uses exactly the same SANE backend as Xsane, it's unlikely that this would solve OP's problem which sounds like a driver issue.

Comment: Yes, there's a chance xsane may not work either.  Simple scan did have problems with my HP scanner though and it turned out that xsane was working fine every time.  If xsane fails too, you'll probably be right.  :)

Comment: SimpleScan works well even with Ubuntu Gnome live USB, but does not work after a fresh installation.

Comment: SimpleScan also works in Antergos Arch linux, but does not works under Manjaro, the symtoms are the same. I'm not sure that its driver problem.

Comment: Under earlier Ubuntu versions (and also under Arch) SimpleScan worked correctly, I'm using it since many years.

Comment: Now I installed xsane, and the symptoms are the same! Scanner does not work physically, xsane make a "fake" scanning process with that growing black rectangle. No errors. Very interesting! Scanner works fine on live usb, so its not a hardware eror on scanner

Comment: @Silken, wait... It works fine using the *same* distro but live? Same kernel? Could you add this additional information to your question?